# How to pass ListBox selected item into file?

Tags: vb.net, batch-file

What I have:

```
Private Sub ChooseProgram_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ChooseProgram.SelectedIndexChanged

Dim curItem As String = ChooseProgram.SelectedItem.ToString()

End Sub

Private Sub Install_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Install.Click

Dim jhin As System.IO.StreamWriter
jhin = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter("C:\Temp\jhin.bat", True)

jhin.WriteLine("$program = " & curitem.string")
jhin.Close()
End Sub
```

I just want to write the string into the file.
How is that possible?

Thx for ur help!
Hannir

UPDATE:

```
' Ensure an item is selected
    If ChooseProgram.SelectedItem Is Not Nothing Then
        curItem = ChooseProgram.SelectedItem.ToString()
    End If
```

I get an error here.

"The Is operator does not accept operands of type " integer " . The operands must be reference types, or permit types , NULL values ​​."

Really thx for ur quick help! @Pro Grammer

If you just click Install, and nothing is selected, it ends in an error. So is it possible to say "You need to select an item before" or the Install button is just clickable when selected an item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters you have to move the declaration of the `curItem` variable out of the `SelectedIndexChanged` method, to what's called *Class level*.

As it stands your variable is accessible within your `SelectedIndexChanged` method only, whereas if you move it to class level it will be accessible by everything within that class (the class in this case is your Form). You then just modify the variable from your `SelectedIndexChanged` method.

```
Dim curItem As String = "" 'We'll start with an empty string.

Private Sub ChooseProgram_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ChooseProgram.SelectedIndexChanged

    curItem = ChooseProgram.SelectedItem.ToString()

End Sub
```

Now you will be able to access the variable from your button and write it to a file.

The last thing you have to do is to close the `StreamWriter` that you create so that it will release the lock on the file. The easiest and best way to do so is wrapping it in an `Using/End Using` block.

```
Private Sub Install_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Install.Click

    Using jhin As System.IO.StreamWriter = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter("C:\Temp\jhin.bat", True)

        jhin.WriteLine("$program = " & curItem)

    End Using
End Sub
```

**EDIT:**

To make your button clickable only when an item is selected, first set the button's `Enabled` property to False via the Property Window in the designer, then use this code in the `SelectedIndexChanged` event:

```
Install.Enabled = ChooseProgram.SelectedIndex >= 0
If ChooseProgram.SelectedIndex < 0 Then Return

curItem = ChooseProgram.SelectedItem.ToString()
```

Comment: Yes it works. What about Pro Grammers answer? Can u help with that error? It's a bit better, because if you just click Install, and nothing is selected, it ends in an error. So is it possible to say "You need to select an item before" or the Install button is just clickable when selected an item?

Comment: @hannir : You better asked Pro Grammer about that, and mark his as the accepted answer if the the error gets fixed. I wrote my answer only to fix your initial problem, while he expanded and improved his to check for problems.

Comment: Maybe u can help me with another little problem. How to get the curItem in ""  -  like $program = "arcTest" ?

Comment: `"$program = " & Chr(34) & curItem & Chr(34)`

Another option being `"$program = """ & curItem & """"`

Comment: @hannir : Got you a solution for making the button clickable when an item is selected. I just remembered it is best done in the `SelectedIndexChanged` event.

Comment: AWESOME! You guys helped me alot! Workds great by the way ;)

Comment: @hannir : Glad we could help you! :)

Answer (score 2):

This is one option:

```
Private Sub Install_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Install.Click
    Dim curItem as String = ""  

    ' Ensure an item is selected
    If ChooseProgram.SelectedItem IsNot Nothing
        curItem = ChooseProgram.SelectedItem.ToString()
    End If

    ' Double checking valid input
    If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(curItem) Then
        ' Handle empty input - Display message, etc
        ' Exit Sub (unless bat handles empty)
    End If

    Dim jhin As System.IO.StreamWriter
    jhin = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter("C:\Temp\jhin.bat", True)

    jhin.WriteLine("$program = " & curItem)
    jhin.Close()
End Sub
```

Instead of using the `ChooseProgram_SelectedIndexChanged` event, you can deal with it from here, since you aren't performing any other actions in that method. If you wanted to still use that event, you would assign the string value into a field which could be accessed across the class. Check out [Visual Vincent's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37856938/6144259) for this example, and also of a `Using` block, which removes the need to call `jhin.Close()` manually and also provides a much clearer format

Comment: I posted my error as an new answer here. Thx for ur quick help :)

Comment: Remember to close the `StreamWriter` when you are done with it.

Comment: Thx for ur help again :)

Comment: Hmm. I'm not sure, but your error could be due to that you use `Is Not` instead of `IsNot`.

Comment: Aghhh! Of course! should be `Not (expr) Is Nothing` or `IsNot`.

Comment: Great :) Is it possible to make the Install button just clickable when an item was selected? @Pro Grammer

Comment: I do not want that the Install button gets clicked then - because there is another Browse button too to browse where to install. I just want to grey "Install" out or something like that - so just when u selected an item, you are ready to go.

Comment: Ohhhh sorry, I misunderstood. On the index change for the ListBox, enable/disable the button according to `ListBox.SelectedItems.Count > 0. Heading out for my lunch, will try and help more when I return :)

Comment: I'm sorry I do not understand how to do that. Enjoy ur meal! Hope you can explain it a bit more after :)

Comment: Vincent already found an solution :) I am so thankful for your help guys - u maked my day happy! :)

Comment: Fantastic :) Glad we could both be of help